# Regroup and sum array in php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I collect a start and end date from my db. I use a function to determine a value per day.

```
$array = array();
       foreach ($db_value as $key => $value) {

      $Variable1 = strtotime($Date1);
      $Variable2 = strtotime($Date2);

      for ($currentDate = $Variable1; $currentDate <= $Variable2;
                                      $currentDate += (86400)) {

      $Store = date('Y-m-d', $currentDate);
      $array[] = array( $Store,
       $value->Value2);
      }

      $result = array_merge($array);
    }
```

This gives the output:

```
 0 => array:2 [▼
    0 => "2019-11-24"
    1 => "4"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    0 => "2019-11-24"
    1 => "10"
  ]
```

However, I would like to shape the array in such a way that I get the sum of the 2nd field per day without duplicates. like:

```
 0 => array:2 [▼
    0 => "2019-11-24"
    1 => "14"
  ]
```

However, I cannot get any further.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the date a key, then sum index `1` if date is same.

```
$result = [];
foreach($array as $v){
    if(isset($result[$v[0]])){
        $result[$v[0]][1] += $v[1];
    }else{
        $result[$v[0]] = $v;
    }
}
$result = array_values($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't follow your previous logic, so perhaps you can sum as you are iterating through your database results, but given your output:

```
<?php

$dates =
[
    [
        '2009-11-24',
        2
    ],
    [
        '2009-11-24',
        5
    ]
];

foreach($dates as $date) {
    $result[$date[0]][] = $date[1];
}
$result = array_map('array_sum', $result);
$result = array_map(null, array_keys($result), $result);

var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '2009-11-24',
    1 => 7,
  ),
)
```

The first foreach produces this as the result:

```
array(1) {
    ["2009-11-24"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(2)
      [1]=>
      int(5)
    }
  }
```

Then the array_map and array_sum results in this:

```
  array(1) {
    ["2009-11-24"]=>
    int(7)
  }
```

The last array_map rejigs into the original format, an array of arrays with the date and the summed values for the first and second index of each.

Comment: There's a slight difference here in that the original values I've used are integers in the arrays, where yours looks to be strings.  The resulting sub-arrays also have integer values.  You could fix this with an intermediate: `$result = array_map('strval', $result);` if you must have string values.